# Why does Navigation keep choosing a different route?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I have a route which I have taken a couple of times using Google Maps navigation and every time I go it takes me one of 3 different ways, even though I start and finish with the same location every time.

In web Google Maps the directions returns 3 results which are 35mins, 40mins and 41mins with varying routes, one is using 3 motorways, another is motorway-town-motorway and the last is through the "backroads".

Is GNavigation making this decision intelligently (traffic reports, time of day etc) or randomly picking me a route of the 3 available? This is in the UK.

Comment: Try turning on the Traffic layer before setting off, that should give you a bit of a visual idea whether there is any major traffic that Navigation is trying to route you around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Navigation uses traffic information in some countries, e.g. USA and UK. If you are in one of those, yep, it will pick an optimal route based on traffic.

Comment: +1 if traffic info is available, it will use it to try and route you around any heavy traffic.